# what is the difference between this.query and this.query.find()? I'm finding it confusing

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm currently following a MERN tutorial wherein I'm building a complete E-commerce application.

This is the class which is used for querying and other purposes.

```
  constructor(query, querystr) {
    this.query = query;
    this.querystr = querystr;
    console.log(this.querystr.keyword);
  }

  search() {
    const keyword = this.querystr.keyword
      ? {
          name: {
            $regex: this.querystr.keyword,
            $options: "i",
          },
        }
      : {};
    this.query = this.query.find({ ...keyword });
    return this;
  }
  
}

export default FeaturesApi;
```

This is the controller from where a new instance of class in being called.

```
export const getallProducts = catchAsyncerror(async (req, res, next) => {
  const apifeature = new FeaturesApi(Product.find(), req.query).search();
  const products = await FeaturesApi.query;
  if (!products) {
    return next(CustomError.noProducts);
  }
  res.status(200).json({ message: "Products found", products });
  return next(CustomError);
});
```

can anybody pls tell me what is the difference between `this.query` and `this.query.find()` as used in the above code? As I understand it, `this.query` should itself be `Product.find()`, so `this.query.find()` would make it `Product.find().find()` right? Where am I going wrong? Pls help

Answer (score 0):

`this.query` refers to the `query` property of an instance of the `FeaturesApi` class. Initially, it is assigned the value of `Product.find()`, which is a Mongoose method that returns a `Query` object that you can use to search and retrieve documents from a MongoDB collection.

In the search method of the `FeaturesApi` class, you are chaining the find method onto the `this.query` property:

```
this.query = this.query.find({ ...keyword });
```

This returns a new Query object that is filtered based on the keyword condition.

So, the difference between `this.query` and `this.query.find()` is that the former refers to the original `Query` object returned by `Product.find()`, while the latter refers to a new `Query` object that is filtered based on the `keyword` condition.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, if this.query is Product.find() how come this.query.find() is not Product.find().find()?. This is my whole confusion. I'm new to class based programming and perhaps that is why I'm finding it difficult to understand.